# How to accelerate append within a class statement

Tags: python, class, oop

I am creating a simulation where I will be utilizing a "company" and "client" dynamic.  In essence, the clients will be allocated to companies and through a shopping simulator, will migrate from company to company throughout.

Because I want to increase the size of the simulation, I am noting that certain append statements become noticably slow when I increase the number of total clients.

Here are my class statements:

```
class Market:
    def __init__(self, clients, companies, year):
        self._clients = clients
        self._companies = companies
        self._year = year
        self._company_objs = [Company(companies, year) for _ in range(0, companies)]
        self._client_objs = [Client(year, companies) for _ in range(0, clients)]
        for client in self._client_objs:
            company = client.get_insurer()
            self._company_objs[company].insure_client(client.get_client_id())

class Company:
    company_id = 0

    @classmethod
    def set_company_no(cls):
        cls.company_id += 1
        return cls.company_id-1

    def __init__(self, companies, year):
        self._company_id = Company.set_company_no()
        self._company_year = year
        self._client_list = []

    def insure_client(self, client_id):
        if self._client_list == []:
            self._client_list.append(client_id)
        else:
            if client_id in self._client_list:
                return
            else:
                self._client_list.append(client_id)

class Client:
    client_id = 0

    @classmethod
    def set_client_no(cls):
        cls.client_id += 1
        return cls.client_id-1

    def __init__(self, year, companies):
        self._client_id = Client.set_client_no()
        self._year = year
        self._insurer = self.assign_company(companies)

    def assign_company(self, companies):
        company = np.random.randint(0, companies)
        return company
```

In terms of potential opportunities, I am thinking that use of an numpy array of predefined size would likely speed this up (and using indexing).  I say predefined since I know that numpy appends can be even slower since it is re-written each time.

This is my first time using a Class / OOP pattern.  I could do this more easily with control flow code, but looking for ideas regarding how a Class construct could be composed more elegantly to perform with speed.

Comment: `append` is an (amortized) constant-time operation. What is slow is scanning the list to see if `client_id` is already there.

Comment: I'm actually confident that my logic would avoid this.  So I can just delete this step.  I will comment it out to see what performance gain I see.  Thank you.

Comment: The explicit check against `[]` is also redundant; if the list is empty, then `client_id in self._client_list` would return `False` immediately.

Comment: @chepner Much faster now.  Thanks for your help!